# Implement WCF with RequestHandler

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF concepts. I see following code code snippet in wcf example. where serivces are implemented with request handler

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public readonly GetDataRequestHandler requesthandler;

    public GetDataResponse GetData(GetDataRequest request)
    {
       return this.requesthandler.Process(request);
    }
}

public class GetDataRequestHandler: RequestHandler<GetDataRequest, GetDataResponse>
{    
    private readonly GetDataImp _getdata;

    public GetDataRequestHandler(GetDataImp _getdata)
    {
        this._getdata = _getdata;
    }

    protected override GetDataResponse OnProcess(GetDataRequest request)
    {
        return _getdata.GetDataValue(request);
    }
}

public abstract class RequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    public virtual TResponse Process(TRequest request)
    {
        return OnProcess(request);
    }

    protected abstract TResponse OnProcess(TRequest request);
}

public class GetDataImp
{
    public GetDataResponse GetDataValue(GetDataRequest request)
    {
        string a="ayan"+request.value;
        GetDataResponse rep = new GetDataResponse();
        rep.Data = a;
        return rep;
    }
}
```

But when I call Service1 using wcftestclient I got null pointer exception like "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WcfServiceLibrary1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." on 'return this.requesthandler.Process(request)' line.

Could any body please explain the problem with new complete example for this kind of implementation?

Comment: You are getting the NullRefEx when the client calls the "GetData" method of your service ?

Comment: yes, I got Null refrence exception. How can i implement the logic so that the problem get resolved.

Comment: "requesthandler" is not instantiated ....